# Several app.config files for one executalbe

Tags: .net, wcf, app-config

I have a WindowsForms project that uses its app config to store some appSettings. Let's call it WinFormsApp.exe

WinFormsApp uses classes from a library that basicaly exposes WCF server connectivity. Let's call it WCFClass.dll

WCFClass.dll is a separate project in a solution and it has its own app.config it which is holds the WCF config.

How can I have two config files loaded at the start of WinFormsApp.exe, so that I don't have to manually merge the contents of two app.configs in one?

Answer (score 2):

For WCF you must merge these configs - `system.serviceModel` section must be in the main application config. Configuration file for .dll is not used. It is used only by WCF test client.

Comment: Thank you. Can there be a merge script for VS?